# API Json data not being rendered by map() in my react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

[My array of API generated "todo" objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejy9E.png)

That is console logged, but i have also saved it as a variable, todosData. Now this variable used to be the same format( array of objects with id, title, completed ) but my hardcoded data. I rendered this with components as my app is made with react. This is the code for it:

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import todosData from "./TodosData";

// Container for every todo object

export default function Todos() {
  const todoItemArray = todosData.map((todo) => {
    return <TodoItem title={todo.title} key={todo.id} completed={todo.completed} />;
  });
  return <div>{todoItemArray}</div>;
}
```

Now as you can see i havent even changed the array name when i switched from hardcoded data to api data. Both were an array of objects, as i mentioned. Just this map method is rendered 0 components to my website. Before it rendered all ( when i hardcoded the values ).
Im completely confused.

This is the fetch() method to get the data. Even though my console.log shows that isnt the problem:

```
let todosData = [];

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => todosData.push(...data))
  .then(() => console.log(todosData));

export default todosData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just store your data in a variable. React does not know when you mutate it. You need to use [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) so that react knows when to re-render your component. Also the place to fetch data is in an effect:

```
export default function Todos() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setTodos(data))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <TodoItem title={todo.title} key={todo.id} completed={todo.completed} />
      )}
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: Seems like i jumped the gun and thought i could just add an api. I havent gotten confident with states yet and the tutorial im using hasnt gone into them yet... okay thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @LeonMichalak Yeah, react state is one of the most important basic concepts. You will for sure need it if you want to do anything interactive or async in react.